# EnableFolderBrowseButton in selecting files not folders when im using CMFCEditBrowseCtrl in MFC c++

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to show file selection and folder activities in the same user interface. `EnableFileBrowseButton()` functions as intended, but when I call `EnableFolderBrowseButton`, it continues to look for files rather than folders.

Can somebody assist me with this? In my search, I'm attempting to find a folder icon image with folder selection.

Comment: *"I want to show file selection and folder activities in the same user interface."* - That's not going to work. It would introduce ambiguity. For example, what should a double-click on a folder do in this hypothetical UI? Select the folder or navigate into the folder to select another file/folder?

Comment: No, it will work we can customize the controls by inheriting the CMFCEditBrowseCtrl class. For files i have created one custom class from CMFCEditBrowseCtrl same for folders also created one more custom class from CMFCEditBrowseCtrl. 
in this way i was able to select the files and folders in the same UI. 
but i couldnt fin the way to set the custom path when we open folder browse.